# Disable button when user clears text from UITextfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I can get the button disabled when the view loads for the first time. Even when the `textfield` is empty. But after sending a message, when I type and remove the text from the `textfield` it doesn't work. The `button` interaction still works and user can send an empty message which is don't want. I wanted to still disable the button when the user types and deletes the text in case they change their mind. Here is my code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var sendButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.textField.delegate = self
        if textField.text!.isEmpty {
            sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let inputText = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

        if !inputText.isEmpty {
            sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        } else {
            sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: You should be checking `textField.text!.isEmpty`, there's no need for `inputText`.

Comment: @mandem112, I have updated my answer, Kindly check

Answer (score 2):

Add listener for your text field, for which you want to disable your action button like this in your **viewDidLoad** method

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionTextFieldIsEditingChanged), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
```

And upon call this method, check for text field is empty or not:

```
@objc func actionTextFieldIsEditingChanged(sender: UITextField) {
     if sender.text.isEmpty {
       sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
     } else {
       sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
     }
  }
```

Comment: How is this answer different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53081834/7734643) one posted below by Sateesh?

Comment: This doesn't work. Still the same problem I had before

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Hey.. I have given my answer.. It's just coincidence that our answer is similar.

Comment: @SachinVsSachin it’s the exact same. You would have been notified when answers are posted and you could have checked if someone had posted the same answer.

Comment: I was not notified. otherwise I wouldn't have posted answer and time difference is only 3 min.

Answer (score 1):

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
```

**Action**:

```
@objc func textChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if !textField.text!.isEmpty {
            sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        } else {
            sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried out all the above solutions but none works at all. I tried out this implementation and its the only one that works for me.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var sendButton: UIButton!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.textField.delegate = self
     if textField.text!.isEmpty {
        sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
   }
 }

@IBAction func sendButton(_ pSender: UIButton) {
        generateMessages()
        self.sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = !(self.textField.text!.isEmpty)
 }

 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let inputText = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        self.sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = !inputText.isEmpty
        return true
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point in your code you would be doing

```
self.textField.text = ""
```

After this, your delegate is not being called. Right after after setting textField empty you need to set your button disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let inputText = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    if !textField.text.isEmpty {
        sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    } else {
        sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    return true
}
```

Check with above code

Answer (score 0):

The below code might help you, I have implemented kind of same functionality.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var sendButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.textField.delegate = self
    if textField.text!.isEmpty {
        sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }

    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ModifiedTextField.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
}

@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if !textField.isEmpty {
        sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    } else {
        sendButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}
```

or you can try creating the action of button and apply the below condition

```
@IBAction func sendButtonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    if !textField.isEmpty{
    // perform your action here
    }

}
```

it wont execute the code if the textField is empty

Comment: How is this answer different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53081834/7734643) one posted below by Sateesh?

Comment: its the same, I took a little more time in posting the answer

Comment: then why not upvote that instead of posting a duplicate?

Comment: @AbhinavJha I have tried this out many times but still doesn't work. thanks